# binding innerHTML's entire contents to a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im having a javascript code wherein im accessing div in aspx page using innerHTML attribute and want to do following:    1) Get entire content of that div tag.
2) Bind the entire contents of that div tag to a variable say res .
3) Give the value in res to a hidden control in aspx page and finally
4) Render that value from hidden field and use it in aspx.cs code behind.

My aspx page is as below

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
 <script type ="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    function inject() 
    {
        var res = document.getElementById('<%= div.ClientID %>').innerHTML.toString();
        document.getElementById('hidden1').value = res;
    }
 </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="BtnAdd_Click" Width="67px" />
 <div id = "div" runat ="server">

 </div>

 <input type = "hidden" id = "hidden1" value = "" />

 <asp:Label ID = "lbl" Text = "Final answer goes here" runat = "server"/>

</asp:Content>
```

and the code behind to access it as as follows

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string str = "* is the capital of *";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public static int count = 1;
    public string res;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder htm = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str[j] == '*')
            {
                string res = "<input type = 'text' id ='" + count + "' value = ''/>";
                htm = htm.Append(res);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                htm = htm.Append(str[j]);
            }
        }
        div.InnerHtml = htm.ToString();
    }


    protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Page.RegisterStartupScript("<Script>", "<Script type='text/javascript'> inject();</Script>");
        string res = Request.Form["hidden1"];
        lbl.Text = res;
    }
}
```

Now code is executing but im not getting the entire content from the innerHTML thing onto res variable in the code behind. By entire content i mean everything within  to  tag. Im sure i have messed it somewhere or if its an wrong approach can i be suggested a better way??

Thanks for taking time onto this

Comment: If all the `BtnAdd_Click()` method does is just invoke the JavaScript `inject()` function, then why not just use a jQuery selector that binds to the click event of the button (`BtnAdd`) and then grab the content in the DIV and put it into the ASP.NET Label? I am confused as to why you are going back and forth to the server when it appears you do not need to.

Comment: you can use asp:label for your content and asp:hiddenfield

Comment: @KarlAnderson im sorry but i have never used jquerry, so was trying with javascript, butif my back and forth method is obsolete, is there any other possible way i can approach using JS??....Thanks for the tip

Comment: @user2470766 - it is not really an issue with JavaScript vs. jQuery, but rather client-side vs. server-side. I was just asking if you were going to the server to have it read values from the client-side only, if you are doing something else on the server and it is just not in your code posted, then that is the reason to go to the server.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Im extremely sorry i should have said that part, the logic is code runs and it creates dynamic controls(TextBox) with some text onto UI, now when the user enters some values into that textbox i need to capture the text and store it in DB.